# finding everything between tags

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to find everything between two tags, even when there is the same tag in the tag (kind of weird explained).

Well here is an example: `this <tag id="1">is an <tag id="2">example</tag> for</tag> tags <tag id="3">in tags</tag>`.

I'm able to get everything between the tags, but not the one which are paired like.

My regex looks like: `<tag id="(.*?)">(.*?)</tag>`

How can I tell my regex to look if there is `<tag>` and then ignore the next `</tag>`? And that an infinite times.

Because I'm working with php, is there maybe another solution which is better and faster?

The output should look like:

```
id => content
- 1 => is an <tag id="2">example</tag> for
- 2 => example
- 3 => in tags
```

Comment: wouldn't [strip_tags](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) do the job?

Comment: thanks, I forgot that I have something between <tag ... >. I added that to my example. If I didn't have the `id` part, which I need, strip_tags would be great.

Comment: You didn't specify output.

Comment: sorry, I just added the output :)

Comment: @CasimirEtHippolyte I think it would be nice to re-open the question in order to give it a narrower answer rather than closing it to a general one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an already structured string with a well know syntax, and PHP has build-in tools to parse this syntax. There's no reason to use a string approach with regex or with string functions.

In this example, I choose `DOMDocument::loadHTML` in place of `DOMDocument::loadXML` to have a more lenient parser, but if you have a well formatted XML document, this change isn't needed.

I assume that each `<tag>` node has an `id` attribute, but if it isn't always the case, you can simply test its presence using `DOMNode::hasAttribute` in the first foreach loop.

```
$html = 'this <tag id="1">is an <tag id="2">example</tag> for</tag> tags <tag id="3">in tags</tag>';

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$state = libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTML($html);
libxml_use_internal_errors($state);

$nodeList = $dom->getElementsByTagName('tag');

$results = [];

foreach ($nodeList as $node) {
    $content = '';
    foreach ($node->childNodes as $child) {
        $content .= $dom->saveHTML($child);
    }
    $results[$node->getAttribute('id')] = $content;
}

print_r($results);
```

Comment: wow great thank you. just a through: is it possible to use the same example for like bbcodes ([b] .. [/b], [url=http://...]my url[/url]) or is that another topic?

Comment: @Mr.Tr33: Same idea, it's also a structured string, search about a bbcode parser.